# What are the benefits of SocketTaskExtensions against Socket asynchronous methods using SocketAsyncEventArgs?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

What are the benefits of SocketTaskExtensions against Socket asynchronous methods using SocketAsyncEventArgs?

It's really confused about either using **Socket.AcceptAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs)** or **await Socket.AcceptAsync()** the only difference that I can see is the not using of SocketAsyncEventArgs which reduces the single object allocation of SocketAsyncEventArgs and provides a much cleaner/less code.

**Socket.AcceptAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs)**

```
private void StartAccept()
{
    SAEA.AcceptedSocket = null;
    bool willRaiseEvent = _listener.AcceptAsync(_eventArgs);
    if (!willRaiseEvent)
        ProcessAccept(_listener, _eventArgs);
}
private void ProcessAccept(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs SAEA)
{
    //do whatever with SAEA.AcceptedSocket
    StartAccept();
}
```

**await Socket.AcceptAsync()**

```
private async Task StartAccept()
{
    Socket AcceptedSocket = await _listener.AcceptAsync();
    //do whatever with AcceptedSocket

    _ = StartAccept();
}
```

Comment: `the only difference that I can see` Isn't that a significant benefit in and of itself?

Comment: It is but I am no expert to tell yet, I have no idea if await _listener.AcceptAsync(); might be allocating internal objects than the Task itself

Comment: When you profiled it, was there a performance issue with either approach?

Comment: `SocketAsyncEventArgs` is not a simple class, but error-prone if you use it even in the slightest wrong way. People (like me) had to use hacks to work with async/await in the past, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/awaiting-socket-operations/ and now with this new extension class everything is officially supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `await` is much simpler / easier than splitting your code between two methods.

Comment: Simply, is that? is there any internal object allocations that I am not aware of than the Task itself?